# Minimum database user permissions using Entity Framework database first approach

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What is the minimum set of database user permissions in SQL Server using Entity Framework database first approach in an ASP.NET MVC app?

Is it only read and write or does EF need some more advanced permissions?

Comment: It very likely also needs execution of stored procedures

Comment: working on EF with Oracle & Database first approach,i am facing problem; not getting full list of the packages (in server explorer) which are supposed to be there, I guess there is some permission issue. Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We typically use the following permissions

Db Access admin,
Db data reader 
And db data writer.

These were sufficient in most cases.

Comment: I cannot find any info about the first choice - db access admin. The closest thing I found was this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174889%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: For anyone still reading this, I think `DB Access admin` here refers to the `db_accessadmin` role: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: And it is unclear to me why ef would need db_accessadmin. ef should not need to add additional users, and granting this permission is a security problem.